# Cannot get live metrics stream on deployed webapi application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights

I have a webapi application with Serilog logging configured to go to Application Insights.
When my webapi application is running locally, I can see the app's logs via the "Search" in Application Insights, and I can also see the Live Metrics Stream.

When the application is deployed however, I can't see the Live Metrics Stream (it says "Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK). Interestingly I can still see the app's logs in the Search function - so the applications own logging is working, but not the Live Metrics data collection.

The [AI troubleshooting documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data#no-data-from-my-server) suggests that this is likely to be a firewall problem, however I've verified that I can reach port 443 of the [live metrics stream ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-ip-addresses) (rt.services.visualstudio.com and rt.applicationinsights.microsoft.com)  from that server with telnet.

The Application Insights Monitor on the server shows that the site is "enabled". The only notification is "Application Insights is already enabled for this application through the application project code. (...)". Originally I had a warning about being unable to collect the metrics, but I added the app pool's identity to the appropriate group and that warning has now gone.

The only real customisation I've done is to remove the AI key from the applicationinsights.config file, and set it in code so that I can have a different AI resource for each environment.

My code to set the instrumentation key in the Startup.Configuration method is as follows:

```
    if (TelemetryConfiguration.Active != null)
    {
        TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationInsightsKey"];
    }
```

Again, this is working locally, so I don't think the problem is in the setting of the AI key in code.

Is there any other "self-logging" that I can turn on for AI to see why it's having trouble gathering or sending the Live Metrics?

Comment: are the up to date versions of the ai assemblies all getting deployed? you could look at the `sdkVersion` field output by the things that are showing up in search to be sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server where your application is deployed - check the location of ApplicationInsights.config. Depending on many factors (like deployment model or application type), the file should be either in the /bin folder, or in the root of the application.

Comment: I had a custom build process that was putting applicationinsights.config into /bin. Thanks! Would be nice if applicationinsights sent some debug information into the portal to help with this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following and let us know if it worked?

1. remove QuickPulseTelemetryModule from ApplicationInsights.config
2. in code, after you've set the instrumentation key, create the module manually:

   ```
   QuickPulseTelemetryModule quickPulseModule = new QuickPulseTelemetryModule();
   QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor quickPulseTelemetryProcessor = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryProcessors.OfType<QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor>().Single();
   quickPulseModule.RegisterTelemetryProcessor(quickPulseTelemetryProcessor);
   quickPulseModule.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);
   ```
3. make sure you keep the reference to the module throughout the application's lifetime.

If the above fails indicating QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor isn't found in the configuration, please check that ApplicationInsights.config is placed correctly when you deploy to a remote server (the fact that things are working locally but not when deployed might be an indicator of the fact that the file is not picked up - along with the fact that QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor doesn't seem to be found in the configuration even though it's in the configuration file). Compare the placement of ApplicationInsights.config in the local setup that works and the remote one that doesn't. If you're stuck, you can try creating both the module and the processor in code. To do that, remove both QuickPulseTelemetryModule and QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor from ApplicationInsights.config (even though that might not even matter), and do the following in code:

```
var quickPulseModule = new QuickPulseTelemetryModule();                
quickPulseModule.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder.Use(next =>
            {
                var processor = new QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor(next);
                quickPulseModule.RegisterTelemetryProcessor(processor);
                return processor;
            });

TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder.Build();
```

Comment: I tried that, the application failed to start with "InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements" on the first line of that new code (where it's creating the QuickPulseTelemetryModule.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is on the first line and not on the second? Sounds like something that might have been thrown by .Single() if configuration is not loaded properly.

Comment: Updated the answer above.

Comment: You were right- there was an off-by-one error in the error message, but I tried wrapping that code in an aggregate exception with a string indicating where it was up to - and it was definitely the second line, creating the processor.
I checked the placement of the applicationinsights.config file - it was in the bin directory. I moved it out to the root, and hey presto I now have Live Metrics! Do you want to add a simpler answer "check placement of applicationinsights.config" and I'll mark that as the answer?